# Finding a point between two points given the points and a distance

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

Given two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, and a third point $(x_3,y_3)$ which is said to be equidistant from both the first two points, how would I find other points which are the same distance the third point is from the first two points.

Ex: $A = (7,3)$, $B = (6,0)$, and $C = (14,-1)$. $C$ is between $A$ and $B$. So the distance between the points is $\sqrt{65}$, so my question is asking how could I find another point which is this same distance between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Hint: Think about the perpendicular bisector of a line.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 What I had tried to do $√(7-x)^2+(3-y)^2$ = $√(6-x)^2+(0-4)^2$ I simplified this down to y = 11-x/3. I believe this will find any point that is equidistant between both the A and B I had specified, but this distance is not equal to $√65$.

Comment: You know that a point lies on a line, and you know it's distance from some given point. $(x - a_x)^2 + (y - a_y)^2 = d^2$ where $y = mx + c$. Substitute the latter into the former to get a quadratic in $x$. You'll find two solutions: The original point, and the point you're looking for.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Sorry i'm a bit confused by this explanation. I'm not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically speaking, all points that are equidistance from points, p and q, all lie on the perdendicular bisector of pq.

So if $p = (x1, y1)$ and $q =(x2, y2)$ are the points, the line pq has slope, $\frac {y2 - y1}{x2 - x1}$.  So the slope of a perpendicular line will have slope m = $-  \frac {x2 - x1}{y2 - y1}$  As the line is a bisector, it will contain the midpoint $mid = (\frac{x1+x2}{2},\frac{y1+y2}{2})$.  So the perpendicular bisector is the line with the equation $y - \frac{y1+y2}{2} = m(x - \frac{x1+x2}{2}) = y - \frac{y1+y2}{2} = -  \frac {x2 - x1}{y2 - y1}(x - \frac{x1+x2}{2})$.

You want to find the points (x,y) where distance((x1,y1),(x,y)) = distance((x2,y2)(x,y)) = distance((x1,y1),(x2, y2)). Where (x,y) are on the line $y - \frac{y1+y2}{2} = -  \frac {x2 - x1}{y2 - y1}(x - \frac{x1+x2}{2})$.

So you have three equations:

$y - \frac{y1+y2}{2} = -  \frac {x2 - x1}{y2 - y1}(x - \frac{x1+x2}{2})$

$\sqrt{(x1 - x)^2 + (y1 - y)^2} = \sqrt{(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2}$

and $\sqrt{(x2 - x)^2 + (y2 - y)^2} = \sqrt{(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2}$

There will be two possible points that satisfy the the equations.

Okay, that's hard.  *BUT* if you are given one of the two points the other will be symmetrically placed on the other side of the midpoint.

Ex: A=(7,3), B=(6,0), and C=(14,−1).

So the midpoint of A and B is M = (6.5, 1.5). C is 14 - 6.5 = 7.5 away from M in the x direction.  C is -1 - 1.5 = -2.5 away in the y directions.  So the 4th point X will also be 7.5 away in the x direction and -2.5 away in the y direction.  So X = (6.5 - 7.5, 1.5 - (-2.5)) = (-1, 4).